# Unable to change Manifest for deployed WPF application

Tags: wpf, deployment, manifest

Well.. what I'm really needing is to allow the user to install two different versions of the same application. Changing the assembly name just generates a lot of errors that require too much work. I've been reading that changing the assembly identity tells WPF that those are different applications and so the second application (it's a ClickOnce) doesn't replace the previously installed. Sadly this cannot be change inside VS2010.

I've changed the MyApp.exe.manifest here, I Think:

**assemblyIdentity name="MyWPFApp_NEWNAME" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86"**

And resigned the manifest this way:

**mage.exe -update MyWPFApp.exe.manifest -certfile D:\MyDir\MyWPFApp_TemporaryKey.pfx**

**mage.exe -update MyWPFApp.application -appmanifest MyWPFApp.exe.manifest -certfile D:\MyDir\MyWPFApp_TemporaryKey.pfx**

the signing states sucessfull, but when trying to open the application it get an error stating that the Hash is misscalculated...

As this is my first try to modify a deployed application with no doubt I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clicking on your start-up project and going to properties. Then in properties in the "Application" tab look for "Assembly Information" button. Click that button and change the desired values. Rebuild your project and then try to get the user to install this version while an older version is still installed.

Comment: Yep... but it stills recognizes the previous installation as the same identity "already installed".

Comment: Is it attempting to install the new version into the same local disk path as the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Solved... (this always happens to me as soon as I post a question) for client to detect the versions as different applications all I needed was to create a different key file (pfx) for each deployment and change the "Name of application group" in the application properties.